# how to update the one key value in list using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to update the only one key value in the list. this my array list, 
I need to update the only the `open: false` for only `day:"MONDAY"`.

```
var bArray =[
  {closingTime: "22:30", openingTime: "06:30", day: "SUNDAY", open: true},
  {closingTime: "22:30", openingTime: "06:30", day: "MONDAY", open: true},
  {closingTime: "22:30", openingTime: "06:30", day: "TUESDAY", open: true}
]
```

My output should be

```
var bArray =[
      {closingTime: "22:30", openingTime: "06:30", day: "SUNDAY", open: true},
      {closingTime: "22:30", openingTime: "06:30", day: "MONDAY", open: false},
      {closingTime: "22:30", openingTime: "06:30", day: "TUESDAY", open: true}
    ]
```

I want to do this using lodash can give the solution for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without lodash in the following way

```js
var bArray =[
  {closingTime: "22:30", openingTime: "06:30", day: "SUNDAY", open: true},
  {closingTime: "22:30", openingTime: "06:30", day: "MONDAY", open: true},
  {closingTime: "22:30", openingTime: "06:30", day: "TUESDAY", open: true}
]

let result = bArray.map(e => e.day == "MONDAY" ? (e.open = false, e) : e);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: one more thing I want to check if open is `true` or `false` in this condition how can I do that

Comment: can you specify the condition exactly ? do you want to add an and condition ?

Comment: yes,`if (e.open == true)` means I want to change to `false`

Comment: `e => e.day == "MONDAY"  && e.open ? `

Comment: something like this  'e.day == "MONDAY" && e.open == true ? (e.open = false, e) : e)' ?

Comment: `let statusList = data.location[0].businessHours.map(el => el.day == day && el.open == true ? (el.open = false, el) : el.day == day && el.open == false? (el.open = true, el) : el);` is my updated code

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with regular JavaScript as well -

```js
var bArray =[
  {closingTime: "22:30", openingTime: "06:30", day: "SUNDAY", open: true},
  {closingTime: "22:30", openingTime: "06:30", day: "MONDAY", open: true},
  {closingTime: "22:30", openingTime: "06:30", day: "TUESDAY", open: true}
]

var result = bArray.map(obj => obj.day === "MONDAY" ? ({...obj, open: false}): obj);

console.log(result);
```

And, using Lodash -

```js
var bArray =[
  {closingTime: "22:30", openingTime: "06:30", day: "SUNDAY", open: true},
  {closingTime: "22:30", openingTime: "06:30", day: "MONDAY", open: true},
  {closingTime: "22:30", openingTime: "06:30", day: "TUESDAY", open: true}
]


function foo(arr) {
  let val = _.find(arr, obj => obj.day === "MONDAY");
  _.set(val, 'open', false);
}

foo(bArray);

console.log(bArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```